# docker-web-1 | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voBxP.jpg)

when i run command docker-compose up and that time error comes, what to do anyone help me?
docker-web-1  | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please include the code for your Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: You can also execute RUN pwd in dockerfile to check the directory in which you are currently in. That might help you finding why its not able to find the manage.py file

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the path to the code file is present properly. The issue here is that it's not able to find the file in the path that was provided.
If that looks correct, please make sure that you include proper permissions inorder for docker compose to build the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in  Dockerfile specific path selected

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

You need to change directory (instead of root dir image) in docker-compose.yml file when you want to run command

```
command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

volumes: 
# without that path you will get 'no such file' error
      - .:/usr/src/app/dir
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not providing the correct path to the file, this might be as a result of using the wrong slash for a specific operating system, it would be more clear if you shared a screenshot.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.  Posting screenshots of code is almost always discouraged; questions like this one can be improved by including the code and other artifacts necessary for a [mcve] directly in the question (not behind links) as text (not images).